# Slim cropper works perfectly fine on my localhost, but gives a 403 forbidden error on server

Tags: javascript, php, server, csrf, cropper

I'm using slim cropper to upload avatar's on my codeigniter project , It works perfectly on my localhost but on the server , the ajax call to the php that does the image upload keeps giving a 403 forbidden error, below is the section of the code:

```
function send(url, data, progress, success, err) {

 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  if (progress) {
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
        progress(e.loaded, e.total);
     });
 }

 xhr.open('POST', url, true);

 xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {

        var text = xhr.responseText;

        // if no data returned from server assume success
        if (!text.length) {
            success();
            return;
        }

        // catch possible PHP content length problem
        if (text.indexOf('Content-Length') !== -1) {
            err('file-too-big');
            return;
        }

        // if data returned it should be in suggested JSON format
        var obj = null;
        try {
            obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        } catch (e) {}

        success(obj || text);
    } else if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        err('fail');
    }
 };

xhr.send(data);
}
```

From what I've read , providing a CSRF token might solve the problem, but the request is made from the same domain and I don't require that on my localhost. What could be the problem?

Comment: check your uploads directory privileges try to make it `770`

Comment: I have done that , granted permissions for all files and folders involved , still the error persists.